# Mysql syntax error server version

Tags: php, mysql

Error

```
INSERT INTO PENILAIAN (ID,KURSUSID,QUEST1,QUEST2,QUEST3,QUEST4,QUEST5,QUEST6,QUEST7,QUEST8,QUEST9,QUEST10)VALUES ('951019105851', ''13'', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '4', '5', '4', '5')
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '13'', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '4', '5', '4', '5')' at line 3

code

```
"INSERT INTO PENILAIAN (ID,KURSUSID,QUEST1,QUEST2,QUEST3,QUEST4,QUEST5,QUEST6,QUEST7,QUEST8,QUEST9,QUEST10)VALUES
('$login_sessionID',
'$kid','$QUEST1','$QUEST2','$QUEST3','$QUEST4','$QUEST5','$QUEST6','$QUEST7','$QUEST8','$QUEST9','$QUEST10')";
```

Comment: `('951019105851', ''13'', ` note the double single quote. Apparently , you already quoted the `$kid` variable

Comment: Use prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error simply guides you

```
''13''
 ^  ^
```

there is additional single quote

1. keep only one `'` pair for code
2. Use prepared statements

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have double quotes on ''13''.
olso i want to ask, does any of the values contain quotes? like this (I'am x)
if you use quotes you should use mysql_real_escape_string when you POST